# data-callback Function in Recaptcha not being called properly

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

Update: I am encountering this issue only with the chrome browser for some reason.

I have in my html head tag a java script that I load using the following statement:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

I am also loading the ReCaptcha java script using the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
```

In the body of my html code, I am calling the following ReCaptcha Code:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="recaptchaCallback" data-sitekey="Key"></div>
```

If I execute the code locally (i.e. on my development computer), everything works fine. Meanwhile, if I publish my Site to a Server, the data-callback function, which is in my script.js file loaded as explained above, does't get called.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Do you remember to update your data-sitekey at Google? ... And do you get an error on your production-environment?

Comment: Thank you Zeth. Yes, the Site Key was updated at Google, and it is working fine in my Dev Environment.

Comment: Do you get an error? Or what does it say in the console? Or how do you know that it doesn't get called? ... Silences can be many things (files not being uploaded, path being incorrect, etc.)...

Comment: My Function only enables a Button, which doesn't get enabled. If I add the function directly into the html code, it is being called properly. Meanwhile, after the button gets clicked, then the Function called by the click event, which is also in the script.js file, doesn't get call. I would like to avoid adding all the code I have in my js file directly into the html code. It appears that the problem is related to how the javascript code is being loaded, but I am not sure what is the problem.